# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jar, export

This error keeps bothering me for a long while. I need to export my java app to `.jar` and when I run it (`java -jar test.jar`) I get this error message. I've checked that the apache-core-4.3.3.jar is included, I've checked that it contains HttpEntity class, I've checked java build path and manifest but everything is OK.

The weirdest thing is that in my code I don't try to import `org.apache.http.HttpEntity` at all. And I've got only 3 classes so I wouldn't miss it.

[image: Library imported]

Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

Classes:

[image: My classes]

**EDIT**
I export it like this, so I think imported jars' content is exported to my `test.jar` file thanks to `Export Java source files and resources`, am I right?

[image: export]

What is the next thing I should do?

Comment: Can you show your manifest file please?

Comment: @Jens edited, I don't see a problem here. :-/

Comment: When you say it is included, do you mean inside the jar? Or inside eclipse like you show in the screenshot? In any case, the fact that you get the exception means that some code or library is using that particular class.

Comment: @MajorT see my last edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting it as a 'JAR file', try using the 'runnable JAR file' wizzard.

Right click your eclipse project -> Export.. -> Runnable JAR file -> Pick your configuration and choose "package required libraries into generated JAR". This will make eclipse do al the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the jars to the classpath in commandline:

```
java -cp <list of jars> -jar test.jar
```

Comment: like java -cp "org.apache.http-core-4.3.3.jar; nextlibrary.jar; nextone.jar" -jar test.jar?

Comment: @2rec Yes but without quotes and pth path name.

Comment: excuse me, pth path name is what exactly?

Comment: @2rec the path to the jar file in your screenshot C:\eclipse\... or you copy the files in the same directory as test.jar

Comment: MajorT's answer is more elegant and also working but thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

Update the class path. It should work